# saving or storing HTTP POST data to a file on linux

Tags: linux, webserver, http, bash-scripting

How to save HTTP 'POST' data to a web server on Linux by the use of bash script or other script? I want the Web server to be able to save the POST data each time when different clients sends data through HTTP POST protocol.

Comment: Which application is POST'ing? A network dump would work, but it might not be the ideal method.

Comment: C based programs from embeded type devices not the real computer.

Comment: Are you suggesting tcpdump?

Comment: Why don't you program the save using a PHP script?

Comment: As @harrymc said just use the site they're posting to, to save the data. While you might not have direct control for the clients you would for the server side. Replace the site and let it save the content or add the content saving bit to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You may program the Web server using [PHP](http://php.net/).

For example code, see :

- [Write Post data to file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742898/write-post-data-to-file-with-php)
- [Print $_POST variable name along with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/print-post-variable-name-along-with-value)

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sending form data through HTTP POST so, $_POST won't work at all. And the second solution:
`file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));`
didn't work at all.
I don't need the contents to be saved in another file. If the contents are stored in variables will also solve my problem.

Comment: Your question specifies HTTP POST. If that's wrong you should rephrase the question.

Comment: But the data is being sent continuously through HTTP POST request. So, why should I change 'HTTP POST' tag? $_POST can't handle text/xml type data even if HTTP POST request is used.

Comment: You might be looking for [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) from which $_POST is derived.

Comment: I had tried that but with no avail.

Comment: Better give a small example of your data and of what goes wrong.

Comment: my http post looks someting like this:

"http://some_url/phpscript.php?key1=data1&key2=data2&key3=data3&key4=data4"

And a phpscript.php file with the content:
`file_put_contents("data.txt", file_get_contents('php://input'));`

but it doesn't work because nothing is stored into data.txt file.

Comment: See [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7525).

Comment: I am not using json and apart from that I've already solved my problem using python.

Comment: I've just tested the codes from your suggested above mentioned link but that did not work. I guess I should stick with python for now.